DuckDB - Unnest map that have different keys
EDIT: as a new duckdb user, I misinterpretted the output syntax as a struct it turns out I had created a map
I have a table that contains a map



Product
Sales




Widget
{Jan=12, Feb=13}


Dongle
{Feb=1, Apr=22}



Is there a way to unpivot this so that I get?



Product
Month
Qty




Widget
Jan
12


Widget
Feb
13


Dongle
Feb
1


Dongle
Apr
22



I know the documenation states that structs must have the same keys, but I don't see a clear way to do this with map.

How do you have a Struct column like that in the first place if it is not possible with DuckDB? Can you share a runnable example?

I have a Python UDF that parses text into key value pairs.

Can you share a Python code example so that we can reproduce this?

Turns out I had mistake the datatype. It's a map, not a struct

Ah right - that makes sense. If you provide your sample data as code, it makes it much simpler to provide answers. I've added an example below.

Unfortunately, 8M rows, and about a 25 keys per row.... need to summarize.

You can get lists of map keys/values and unnest() them.

.map_keys()
.map_values()

Input
duckdb.sql("""
create table tbl as (
   select
      unnest(['Widget', 'Dongle']) as Product,
      unnest([
         map(['Jan', 'Feb'], [12, 13]),
         map(['Feb', 'Apr'], [1, 22])
      ]) as Sales
)   
""")

┌─────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ Product │         Sales         │
│ varchar │ map(varchar, integer) │
├─────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ Widget  │ {Jan=12, Feb=13}      │
│ Dongle  │ {Feb=1, Apr=22}       │
└─────────┴───────────────────────┘

Output
duckdb.sql("""
from tbl
select 
    Product,
    unnest(map_keys(Sales)) as Month,
    unnest(map_values(Sales)) as Qty
""")

┌─────────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ Product │  Month  │  Qty  │
│ varchar │ varchar │ int32 │
├─────────┼─────────┼───────┤
│ Widget  │ Jan     │    12 │
│ Widget  │ Feb     │    13 │
│ Dongle  │ Feb     │     1 │
│ Dongle  │ Apr     │    22 │
└─────────┴─────────┴───────┘


Yup, that was it. Apparently fighting with the unpivot wasn't worth it either. Thank-you

In the original version of the question, the Sales column was
presented as though the values were strings such as '{Jan=12, Feb=13}'.
The following accordingly addresses the question of how one would
proceed if the Sales data were presented in this form.
Let's therefore begin with a TSV file:
Product Sales
Widget  {Jan=12, Feb=13}
Dongle  {Feb=1, Apr=22}

In the following, these JSON-like strings are first converted to valid JSON,
and then the DuckDB JSON extension is used to produce the desired result.
For the sake of clarity, the main steps are shown as distinct SQL statements:
LOAD json;

# Read in the data
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t AS
  FROM read_csv('sales.tsv', sep="\t");

# Convert to JSON:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE u AS
  FROM t
  select Product, 
    regexp_replace(regexp_replace(Sales, '=', ':', 'g'),
      '([A-Z][a-z][a-z])', '"\1"', 'g')::JSON as Sales;

# Use unnest to produce the Month and Qty columns:
select
  Product,
  unnest(json_keys(Sales)) as Month,
  unnest(list_transform(json_keys(Sales), x -> Sales[x]::INTEGER)) as Qty
from u;

Output:
┌─────────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ Product │  Month  │  Qty  │
│ varchar │ varchar │ int32 │
├─────────┼─────────┼───────┤
│ Widget  │ Jan     │    12 │
│ Widget  │ Feb     │    13 │
│ Dongle  │ Feb     │     1 │
│ Dongle  │ Apr     │    22 │
└─────────┴─────────┴───────┘


Caveat: the above "translation" of the original Sales data to JSON is of course potentially brittle.
